Odoo - can't compare dates for setting a computed field using @api.depends
Using Odoo 16, using Odoo.sh
I am trying to set a date in a model that should be the furthest in the future of the dates among the related objects from a one2many field. So I have a computed field with a @api.depends computation to iterate through the one2many and find + assign this data to a field.
Everything in my below code compiles and upgrades without problem, but I get an error when I trigger the @api.depends function by adding a order_line_ids:
if order_line.delivery > record.full_delivery_date:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'bool'
Relevant code in primary model operations.purchaseorder:
full_delivery_date = fields.Date(string="Full Delivery Date (calculated)", compute='_compute_deliver_date', default=lambda self: fields.Date.today())

order_line_ids = fields.One2many('operations.purchaseorderline','purchase_order_id',string="Order Lines")

@api.depends('order_line_ids')
def _compute_deliver_date(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.order_line_ids:
            for order_line in record.order_line_ids:
                if order_line.delivery > record.full_delivery_date:
                    record.full_delivery_date = order_line.delivery

Relevant code in co-model operations.purchaseorderline:
purchase_order_id = fields.Many2one('operations.purchaseorder',string='Purchase Order')
delivery = fields.Date("Promised Delivery Date")


What should the compute function do when the field is not set?

It doesn't need to do anything, as I have a default value on the date field it sets. Also, that's not the error that I am getting (there is an error for the function failing to set the record, I've gotten that on other projects, but it's not what I'm seeing here).

You're comparing False with a date object. That's it. You have to continue your loop without comparison if there is no date set in delivery. Odoo will have False in Date and Datetime fields if nothing is set. So you have to care about that in comparisons.

After adding the several if statements needed to guard-rail against empty fields, it works. Thank you for pointing me in the right way @CZoellner !!

As per comment from @CZoellner the issue was because I had not put handling into the code for when order_line.delivery was empty. Correct code below:
@api.depends('order_line_ids')
    def _compute_full_delivery_date(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.order_line_ids:
                for order_line in record.order_line_ids:
                    if order_line.delivery:
                        if record.full_delivery_date:
                            if order_line.delivery > record.full_delivery_date:
                                record.full_delivery_date = order_line.delivery
                        else:
                            record.full_delivery_date = order_line.delivery


You can skip your if record.order_line_ids:, because the for each loop won't do anything, if there are no lines.
